# codeigniter append ; after word with &

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

My application has form with normal html fields. I add this value &Test to text field. But that value read as &Test; I cant find the issue. Is it codeigniter issue? How can i fix it.

This is part of that form.

```
 <?= form_open_multipart('broker/statement/' . $period_info->id, $attributes); ?>
 <?php

        $section_1 = array(
            "Amortisation",
            "Depreciation",
            "Allowance For Bad &amp; Doubtful Debts",
            "Retirement Benefit Obligations",
            "(Profit)/Loss On Disposal Of Fixed Assets",
            "Interest Expense",
            "Interest Income",
            "Dividend Income",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        );
?>

 <?php for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($section_1); $x++) { ?>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <?php if (trim($section_1[$x]) == "") { ?>
                    <input name="cf_1_lbl[]" style="text-align: left; width:220px;" type="text" id="cf_1_lbl<?= $x ?>"  /><?php
                } else {
                    echo $section_1[$x];
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input name="cf_1_col1[]" id="cf_1_col1<?= $x ?>" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="cf_1_col2[]" id="cf_1_col2<?= $x ?>" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
 <?php } ?>

 <?= form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: can you `print_r($cf_1_lbl);` and other array too and update answer pls.

Comment: @karanthakkar i updated it. remove set value things. Please check again.

Comment: Where does it read `&Test;`? In DB? Also, can you show how do you process the form in your controller?

Comment: &test value enter to form by user. When submit the form this value show as &test; thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `&test` use `&amp;test`  & symbol is used to print special characters in html .. if u want to print `"&"` in html u have to use `"&amp;"`